# Flutter File.toString without 'File:...' to share image

Tags: flutter, file, dart, path, filepath

Trying to get the file path to a string to share but when I print it is starting with 'File: ...'

Is there another method besides toString that I should be using to get the same path without these characters?

```
List<String> sharableFile = List<String>();

  void shareFile() {
    print(path.basename(photos[0].name.toString()))
    print(photos[0].name.toString());
    sharableFile.add(photos[0].name.toString());
    Share.shareFiles(sharableFile);
  }
```

output of the two print statements are:

flutter: IMG_0005.JPG'

flutter: File: '/Users/firstlast/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9A654C10-BD7B-4D39-8BDB-A47E8D0C1AF6/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0005.JPG'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `File`'s path, just use its [`path` property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/path.html) instead of calling `toString()` on it.

Note that if you want an absolute path, you might need to use use the [`absolute`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File-class.html) property to get an absolute version of the `File` object first.